# Windows Server Network Routing not working

Tags: routing, windows-server-2019

I have the following setup:

**Server (Windows Server 2019)**
NIC 1 (only IPv4):

- IP: 192.168.2.10/24
- Gateway: 192.168.2.1 (Internet-Router which also does DHCP)
- DNS: 192.168.2.10

NIC 2 (only IPv4) connected via swtich to Network Connected Appliance

- IP: 192.168.100.248/16

**PC (Windows 10 Pro)**
 - IP: 192.168.2.13/24
 - Gateway: 192.168.2.1 (Internet-Router which also does DHCP)
 - DNS: 192.168.2.10

**Network Connected Appliance**
 - LAN-IP: 192.168.100.250/16
 - WAN-IP: 192.168.2.99/24 (network of the internet router)

The goal here is to be able to connect from the PC to the Appliance.
The Network on the Appliance is fiexed and cannot be changed (therefore the IP/MASk on NIC 2 have to stay as well)

On the Server I installed Routing and RAS Feature and set up LAN-Routing.

The PC still cannot ping or connect to the Appliance.

On the PC I then added this route:
  - route add /p 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.168.2.10

The PC can now ping the NIC 2 of the Server but not the 192.168.100.250.

Anything I'm missing here?
PS: ICMPv4 is allowed for everything in the firewall and I even t4ested with firewall off.

**EDIT:**
I found a route on the appliance that goes like this (cannot be edited or deleted):

- Target-Address: 192.168.2.0/24
- Next-Hop: 192.168.2.131

**Solution**

- I moved the DHCP-Role from the Router to the Server
- I opend the Routing and RAS MMC (Start -> Run -> RRASMGMT.MSC). Using the Startmenu tile gave me problems (dont ask me why)
- Right-Click on my Server -> Configure Routing & RAS
- Select custom -> Check NAT & Lan-Routing
- Expand IPv4 -> Right-Click on general -> new routing protocol -> NAT (this would give me an error when Routing & RAS was opened through the Start-Menu Tile)
- Right-Click on NAT -> New interface

  - NIC 1 -> select the private option
- Right-Click on NAT -> New interface

  - NIC 2 -> select the public option and check enable NAT on this interface
- Done, ping is working and access to the appliance is working as well ;-)

I marked the answer that lead me to this solution.

regards
Alkahna

Comment: The suffixes after the IP addresses indicate they're on different subnets. You have to redirect outgoing requests for whatever task it is your "appliance" does to its IP in the Server firewall, so that Server knows that this requests goes to the "appliance" only. Otherwise, the Server will broadcast the requests wide on its own subnet, with only one PC connected. Best bet: you bridge NIC 1 and 2, and you'll solve your connectivity issue.

Comment: Does the Appliance have a separate Internet connection (not going through the server)?

Comment: @user1686 the appliance does have a wan connection which is configured by the company who made it and we cannot modify that either

Comment: @Didier I have a firewall rule that allows ICMP traffic for everything. So why cant I ping the appliance?

Comment: I don't know what the "appliance" is, but for ICMP to work, it must be supported by the recipient of the messages the Server sends it. You said the "appliance" has its own WAN connection and that you can't modify it. Maybe there's something wrong with those settings, due to, I don't know, a recent firmware update, or power failure?

Comment: The appliance is fine because its working in its own network with the old server just fine. And it does respond to ping from the server fine al well. Just the pc cannot get a response due to a static route on the appliance (added info in my question above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing on the server is fine. Routing on the *appliance* is a problem.

Remember that every packet is routed individually. Just because you've set up routing in one direction, **does not mean** responses from the appliance will automatically be sent back the exact same way. In other words, the appliance does not "remember" that it received the request through your server – it needs to have a route added telling it so.

Right now, because it has a /16 subnet mask configured, the appliance will think that your PC is in the same subnet – it will not send the packet through the server nor through any other gateway, but will expect to directly reach your PC on the same switch.

(But even if the appliance had a /24 subnet mask, it would send its replies through *its own* "default gateway" – it still wouldn't automatically know that it needs to reply via your server.)

The possible solutions are:

- Add a route **on the appliance** for 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.100.248; this will take priority over the /16 subnet mask.
- Enable "Proxy ARP" on the server, so that it will respond to ARP queries for 192.168.2.x on NIC 2 (but not on NIC 1!).
- Enable SNAT (masquerading) on the server, so that it will rewrite your PC's requests to make it look like they come from the server itself. Since the appliance only sees the server's IP address from the 'same' subnet, it knows where to send the reply as well.

Solution #3 *might* be possible using Windows Server RRAS, but #2 although technically very simple will probably need third-party software.

Comment: ok that makes sense. In the appliance I found a route that says Target-Address: 192.168.2.0/24 ; Next-Hop: 192.168.2.131. 192.168.2.131 is the WAN Interface and that route cannot be changed. So I guess your suggestion #1 is not possible then?

Comment: Well, you can still override it by adding even smaller routes (e.g. two /25's or four /26's). But I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do so if the appliance already uses the subnet for its own connection. And unfortunately the presence of this route definitely makes solution #2 impossible, although solution #3 should still work.

Comment: Come to think of it – does the appliance use the same "Internet-Router" (192.168.2.1) as your server does? Is it connected to _the same_ 192.168.2.0/24 subnet as your server and your PC, or are they actually two different subnets with identlcal numbering? (This information really should have been part of your original post...)

Comment: the wan network of the appliance is coming from the same internet router yes (added the information above)

Comment: how would I configure SNAT? And I would need to have DHCP on the server rather than the router right? Something like this: https://serverfault.com/questions/436425/snat-on-windows-2008/870513#answer-870513 ??

Comment: Hmm, but then what prevents the PC from directly reaching the appliance on the 192.168.2.x interface? (And, in fact, given the connections I'm not sure what prevents your current routing from working either (it's asymmetric, but that should not be an issue). This probably needs a different answer and more investigation.)

Comment: I think it has to do that the appliance does some weid/magic stuff on the wan interface since it cannot be connected to or be reached via ping. But I found a solution that works (updated post)

Comment: In that case please post your own answer instead...